# Android Intent not starting activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm having issues getting startActivity(intent) to actually open the next activity. when I press the associated button it's printing the string to the debug console, but the new activity just isn't starting. Am I doing something wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button camBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    camBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            startCameraOption(view);
        }
    });

}

public void startCameraOption(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraOption.class);
    intent.putExtra("Launcher","Launched.");
    System.out.println("Starting next activity,");
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

There's my MainActivity.

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.sample.cloudvision">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.google.sample.cloudvision.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraOption">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PictureChosenClass">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the CameraOption class declared as an Activity in your manifest?

Comment: @zgc7009 Yes it is.
The app isn't crashing, it's just staying on the MainActivity rather than opening CameraOption.

Comment: Post your `MainActivity.java` class and `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Odd... what is in CameraOption.class?

Comment: Check CameraOption class declared in manifest or not ? If you have same issue add your logcat

Comment: @NitinKarande yes it is declared, as I said to zgc7009

Comment: @zgc7009
It's just a class with a camera viewer in it, if I use that as my MainActivity it runs on it's own perfectly well.

Comment: Paste your logcat error or exception

Comment: @NitinKarande it isn't throwing an error or exception, it isn't crashing, the next activity just isn't starting

Comment: @shashanth added them to the original post

Comment: Have you tried running the app in the debugger?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes that is how I'm running it.

Comment: Try to comment this line **System.out.println("Starting next activity,");** .. I think there is problem on startActivity (). So comment your print line

Comment: Also try cleaning your project and then rebuild;

Comment: Please add `activity main.xml`

Comment: Show us the CameraOption activity file

Comment: @eenvincible
There's really no point, just to check that wasn't the problem I've replaced it with a blank "Hello World" page and it still won't launch that.

Comment: Im gonna take a shot in the dark and say CameraOption does not extend Activity

Comment: @WillEvers it extends MainActivity

Comment: That's part of you problem. change it to extend Activity or AppCompatActivity and lmk if that works

Comment: @WillEvers

Thanks a lot mate. change it to Activity and it works great :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments you need to change CameraOptions to extend AppCompatActivity or Activity instead of MainActivity